Trace of product of symmetric matrix, Gram matrix and outer product of vectors
Suppose $u^1$, $u^2$, $u^3$ and $w$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $B$ be the matrix with entries $w_i w_j$ and $C$ be the matrix with entries the inner product $u^i \cdot u^j$. For the identity matrix $I$ and a bounded (trace of $MM^\top \leq c$) symmetric matrix $M$, we let $A=I+\delta M$ for some small $\delta$. My goal is to show that there is $\delta>0$ and $\delta'>0$ independent of the choices of $u^i$ and $w$ such that
$$\text{tr}(ABC)=\sum^3_{i,j,l=1}A_{ij}w_jw_lu^l\cdot u^i\geq \delta'\left|\sum^3_{i=1}w_iu^i\right|^2.$$
We first reduce the inequality to
$$\left|\sum^3_{i=1}w_iu^i\right|^2+\delta\sum^3_{i,j,l=1}M_{ij}w_jw_lu^l\cdot u^i\geq \delta'\left|\sum^3_{i=1}w_iu^i\right|^2.$$
If $|w|=0$ or $\max_i|u^i|=0$, then it is done. Therefore, by dividing $|w|$ and $\max_i|u^i|$ on both sides, we can assume $|u^i|\leq 1$ and $|w|=1$. It is reduced to show that
$$\left|\sum^3_{i=1}w_iu^i\right|^2+\delta''\sum^3_{i,j,l=1}M_{ij}w_jw_lu^l\cdot u^i\geq 0.$$ for some $\delta''>0$. I think it is enough to show that
$$\delta'''\left|\sum^3_{i,j,l=1}M_{ij}w_jw_lu^l\cdot u^i\right|\leq \left|\sum^3_{i=1}w_iu^i\right|^2.$$
But I do not have any idea how to proceed. I have tried some numerical examples, I think that the statement is true.

Do $\delta$ and $\delta'$ depend on $M$?

I think they should depend on $M$.

@user1551 Someone has edited my post and twisted my meaning, I'm sorry about that.

Feasible choices of $\delta$ and $\delta'$ may not exist, even if they depend on $M$. Let $U=\pmatrix{u^1&u^2&u^3}$. In matrix form, your inequality can be written as
$$
\operatorname{tr}(ABC)
=\operatorname{tr}(Aww^TU^TU)
=w^TU^TUAw
\ge\delta'\|Uw\|^2,
$$
i.e.,
$$
w^TU^TUMw\ge(\delta'-1)\|Uw\|^2
\quad\text{for all choices of $U$ and $w$.}
$$
In particular, if the first row of $U$ is $v^T$ and the other two rows are zero (or approach zero), your inequality would imply that
$$
\delta(v^TMw)(w^Tv)\geq (\delta'-1)(v^Tw)^2
\quad\text{for all choices of $v$ and $w$.}
$$
Now let
$$
M=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&0&0},\quad
v=\pmatrix{1\\ 0\\ 0},\quad
x=\pmatrix{1\\ -1\\ 0},\quad
y=\pmatrix{t\\ -1\\ 0}.
$$
If we put $w=x$, since $\delta(u^TMx)(x^Tu)=-\delta<0$ and $(\delta'-1)(u^Tx)^2=\delta'-1$, the parameter $\delta'$ cannot be chosen to be $1$. But then if we put $w=y$ and let $t\to0^+$, we have
$$
\delta(u^TMy)(y^Tu)=-\delta t<(\delta'-1)t^2=(\delta'-1)(u^Ty)^2
$$
regardless of the magnitudes of $\delta$ and $\delta'$.

I am so sorry not to make the question clear, $u^i$ should be a set of vectors and $w$ is a single vector.

@mnmn1993 I see. I am sorry that I have misread your question.

@mnmn1993 Fixed. If I understand your question correctly, I think the answer is still negative.
